# Objective C error Thread stops running

Tags: objective-c, methods

I am trying to make my code run, but it always stops.
Can someone of you help me solve the problem.
For some reason it wont accept this.

```
-(Animal *) getAnimalAt:(int)input {
    //NSLog(@"show input %ld", input);
    Animal *ani = [animals objectAtIndex:input];
    return ani;
}
```

I call this method in my main by :

```
for(int i=0;i< count;i++){
        Animal *ani = [farm getAnimalAt:i];
        NSLog(@"ani :  %@",[ani makeSound]);
        NSLog(@"ani :  %@",[ani doFly]);
    }
```

If you need any more info or code please ask.

Also do any of you have found a good tutorial? I cant seem to find one?
Or a site like codingbat would be very helpfull.

Comment: I am guessing animals is an array? If so, is `input` less than the number of elements in `animals`

Comment: well, the main problem is the first method i guess, since i am nobish at it. I changed the method to alway return the object at index 1, and i have 2 elements in my array (it is indeed a NSmutableArray) and still the code failed.. I get no errors just debug window and breakpoint

Comment: Is there any error printed to the console explaining the problem?

Comment: @iain no error just breakpoint

Comment: How do create `animnals` and what determines the value of `count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If animals is just an `NSArray` you could remove the `getAnimalAt:` method and just use the NSArray. Then you could do something like:

```
for (Animal *ani in animals) {
    NSLog(@"ani :  %@", [ani makeSound]);
    NSLog(@"ani :  %@", [ani doFly]);
}
```

which will prevent any problems with `count` being greater than the number of elements in `animals`